# How to depend on previously included templates in Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: templates, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a job template that is included in a pipeline a number of times. The template jobs should execute in parallel, and the final job should only execute when all template jobs have completed.

In the examples below, I have simplified both files as much as possible.

The template file:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: name
  type: string

jobs:
- job: test${{ parameters.name }}
  displayName: 'Test ${{ parameters.name }}'
  dependsOn: [] # Makes sure to run in parallel with other jobs.

  steps:
  - checkout: none
```

The template file is included in the main pipeline file:

```yaml
trigger: none

jobs:
- template: templates/test.yml
  parameters:
    name: 'A'

- template: templates/test.yml
  parameters:
    name: 'B'

- job: depender
  displayName: 'Depends on template jobs'
  dependsOn:
    testA
    testB

  steps:
  - checkout: none
```

When trying to run the pipeline, I get the following error:

> Job dependee depends on unknown job testA testB.

[image: Error message]

I would expect that two jobs get the names `testA` and `testB` after template expansion, but this does not seem to happen.

**How can I make my job depend on jobs previously included using templates?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax mistake in `dependsOn`. Please use this:

```
jobs:
- template: template-test.yml
  parameters:
    name: 'A'

- template: template-test.yml
  parameters:
    name: 'B'

- job: depender
  displayName: 'Depends on template jobs'
  dependsOn:
  - testA
  - testB

  steps:
  - checkout: none
```

[image]